# What is the Bash command to create a hardlink to a directory in OS X?

Tags: bash, filesystems, mac

How do you create a hardlink (as opposed to a symlink or a Mac OS alias) in OS X that points to a directory? There is the command "ln target destination" but that only works when the target is a file.

I know that Mac OS, unlike other Unix environments, does allow hardlinking to folders (this is used for Time Machine, for example) but I don't know how to do it myself. I am also aware that using directory hardlinks is not "best practice" as it can cause some programs to recurse infinitely while scanning a tree.

Comment: Note: this question ported from my SO account as more relevant for this forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly in BASH then. However... I found an article here that discusses how to do it indirectly: http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.23/23.11/ExploringLeopardwithDTrace/index.html by compiling a simple little program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc != 3)
      return 1;
   int ret = link(argv[1], argv[2]);
   if (ret != 0)
      perror("link");
   return ret;
}

$ gcc -o hlink hlink.c -Wall
```

Comment: This is the road to madness.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the  question on Stack Overflow:

[What is the Bash command to create a hardlink to a directory in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80875/what-is-the-bash-command-to-create-a-hardlink-to-a-directory-in-os-x)

Comment: I know ;-) It's my own question. I figured it would be happier living on serverfault

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be impossible.

From `man 2 link`:

> `int link(const char *path1, const
>   char *path2);`
>
> ```
>  ....
> ```
>
> In order for the system call to
>   succeed, path1 must exist and both
>   path1 and
>        path2 must be in the same file system.  As mandated by POSIX.1, path1
>   may not be
>        a directory.

I tried the code in the other answer on MacOS X 10.5.6 - it didn't work when trying to create a link from a directory to the same name in the same directory.

However it *does* work if the two resulting directories don't have the same parent.  It's necessary to read the linked article to find that out.

Comment: Apple specifically extended their link syscall to allow this behavior in limited circumstances to allow TimeMachine backups to consume less space, which still being logically complete

Comment: but haven't updated the man page to say so ;-)

Comment: The Open Group page (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ln.html) for ln says, "If the -s option is not specified, whether a directory can be linked is implementation-defined."  And my link page (on Ubuntu) doesn't say that (although this obviously doesn't work on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

I heard it was intentionally disabled, since it can get complicated when you change the  hard links to `.` and stuff.